# PHP domdocument manipulation issues

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a question regarding the domdocument.

My `$html` contains something like

```
texts …paragraph..

<table class='test'>
   tr and td...
</table>

texts and more texts
```

I want to detect if there my html variable has a table element. If so, wrap the other texts in `<p>` tag.

so it will be

```
<p>texts …paragraph..</p>

<table class='test'>
   tr and td...
</table>

<p>texts and more texts</p>
```

My codes is like

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlString);

$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');

     foreach ($tables as $table) {
        //I am not sure what to do next...
     }
```

Can someone help me out about this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

I didnt test this but.

```
$html  = preg_replace('/(<table.*</table>)/i','<p>$1</p>', $html);
```

Hope it helps...